# How can I get my windows' menus to appear on their own row below the titlebar?

Tags: 16.04, menu, globalmenu

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't used Ubuntu for a while and I see various settings have changed again.

In my last Installation (I think it was either a 12.x or 14.x install) I had configured it to locate window menus in their respective windows and those menubars were positioned below the window's titlebar (so the global menubar was also disabled), so my Firefox windows looked like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| [X][-][O] Mozilla Firefox                                    |
| File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help                  |
| ( Google.com x ) ( Mozilla.com x ) ( AskUbuntu x )           |
```

Now in 16.04 I see I can still move menus back to their respective windows, but the menubars now obscure the window title - which in many windows displays useful information (such as the current filename):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| [X][-][O] File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help        |
| ( Google.com x ) ( Mozilla.com x ) ( AskUbuntu x )           |
```

This is just as annoying as the global menubar. Is there any way to get my old configuration back?